# Get text + data in SQL select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

I'm trying to get the value of a variable using SQL select queries. Nothing new here.

```
SELECT p.ProductCode FROM Products_Joined AS p
```

However, I am wondering if it's possible to prefix text to that result like;

```
SELECT 'XJ' + p.ProductCode FROM Product_Joined AS p
```

So it would look like *XJ2156*. I'm trying to prefix the data with a predefined string of text. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is exactly what you said in the question:

```
SELECT 'XJ' + p.ProductCode FROM Product_Joined AS p
```

Note that this only works as long as `ProductCode` is a text type (`varchar`, `nvarchar`...).
If it's numeric, you have to convert it to text first:

```
SELECT 'XJ' + CAST(p.ProductCode AS varchar(30)) FROM Product_Joined AS p
```

Comment: It actually is a text type, *don't be afraid to try new things...*

Comment: @user1090389: I don't get the "don't be afraid" part. So did it work now for you?

Comment: It was a memo to myself... Yes, it worked, I'll accept as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is wrong with your code. I assume ProductCode is an int? SQL has crazy implicit casting rules which cause 'XJ' to be converted to an int... Solution:

```
SELECT 'XJ' + convert(nvarchar(4000), p.ProductCode) FROM Product_Joined AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of + you have to use pipe  ||

```
     SELECT 'XJ' || p.ProductCode FROM Product_Joined AS p
```

Comment: my mistake .. I was posting as for oracle database syntax .. :(